# Правильное употребление

Tags: выбор-слов, падежи

Как правильно говорить "Ты хотел опята?" или "Ты хотел опят?". Есть ли какое-то правило употребления в том или ином случае?

Comment: Очень хороший вопрос!

Answer (score 3):

Конечно "опят". Мн.ч. р.п. "Нет опят". Ещё эти грибы во множественном числе могут называться "опёнки". 
Ваш вопрос напомнил мне приезжих отдыхающих, которые на пляже говорят: "Я хочу раки, а ты будешь раки?". Это же изнасилование русского языка.

Хотя, поразмыслив, дополню, зависит от контекста:

Можно сказать, например: "Я слышал, что ты проголодался. Ты хотел опят? Жаль, но они кончились". Тут будет родительный падеж.

А можно сказать: "Какие грибы ты думал увидеть в лесу? Слышал, ты хотел найти опята? Извини, они тут не растут". Тогда будет винительный падеж.

Comment: спасибо за развернутый ответ

Comment: (1)Хотел найти опята. Найти (что?) опята, переходный глагол "найти", управление В.п. Глагол "хотеть" здесь только вспомогательный глагол. (2)Хотел (чего?) опят, глагол "хотеть" употреблен как непереходный, управление Р.п.

Comment: Стихи для детей с ошибкой: "Как увидите опят,собирайте всех подряд".

Answer (score 3):

Правильно: ***Ты хотел опят?***

Дело в том, что существительное ОПЯТА (ед.ОПЁНОК) не совсем обычное. Оно склоняется так же, как существительные КОТЯТА, МЕДВЕЖАТА и другие одушевлённые существительные с суффиксом -ат, ят. Существительные МАСЛЁНОК - МАСЛЯТА относятся к этой же группе.

***Ср.: Ты видел котят. - Ты хотел опят.***

Comment: Ты видел котят. В.п. совпадает с Р.п. для одушевл. сущ. Ты хотел опят. Глагол "хотеть" в этом случае является непереходным и управляет Р.п., хотя  других случаях он может быть переходным и управлять В.п. Особенность сущ. опёнок - опята не имеет значения.

Comment: София, одуш. существительные на -онок, -ёнок (-ат,-ят во мн.ч.) в Р.и В.п.мн. ч. имеют нулевое окончание. К этой группе относятся и неодуш. сущ. МАСЛЁНОК и ОПЁНОК. Поэтому ХОТЕЛ ОПЯТ и МАСЛЯТ. Автора вопроса интересует именно окончание Р. и В. мн.числа неодушевлённого существитеьного ОПЯТА. Другие неодуш.существительные на -онок, -ёнок в Р. и В.п. имеют другие окончания. Ср.:бочонок - бочонков - бочонки. Тоже на -онок, но чередования с -ат нет. ОПЯТА и МАСЛЯТА в этом случае действительно особенные существительные.

Comment: Хотел опят, маслят, грибов, конфет - это один и тот же Р.п., он не имеет отношения к одуш./неодушевленности. А вот "вижу опята и вижу котят" - здесь разные формы связаны именно с  одуш. и неодуш. существительными.

Answer (score 2):

***"Ты хочешь опят?"*** и ***"Ты хочешь опята?"*** - оба варианта возможны. Первое сейчас употребляется много чаще. Но это частота определяется не столько даже разницей в смысле (она есть, но не четкая), сколько традицией и аналогией.

//======

Попробую пояснить, хотя это довольно муторно...

Вообще-то вопрос этот из серии "если кит - и вдруг на слона - кто кого сборет?"

Глагол "хотеть" может управлять и родительным, и винительным падежом.
Давайте разберемся сначала с единственным числом.
Для одушевленных существительных падежи совпадают: *"Ты хочешь щенка?"* - и никаких вопросов не порождают.

Для неодушевленного уже сложнее. Глагол "хотеть", возможно как раз под влиянием формы для одушевленных объектов, опционально изменил управление с винительного на родительный - оставаясь при этом глаголом переходным. Первая тенденция требует одной формы, второй факт - другой. "*Ты хочешь ножик?*" - *"Ты хочешь **о**рдена?"*. Между этими двумя случаями есть небольшая смысловая разница, грамматисты её прекрасно знают, я здесь полный разбор опускаю, ограничусь частным указанием, что первое тут означает конкретное реальное желание, второе - отдаленное, абстрактное или несбыточное. Но это не строго.

Множественное число в принципе работает по тем же правилам, но в силу традиции частота родительного падежа сильно перевешивает. В тех же контекстах *"Ты хочешь ножиков"* будет употребляться чаще, чем *"ты хочешь ножики?"*. Возможно потому, что категория конкретности у множественного числа заметно ниже, чем у единственного. Тем не менее винительный падеж все еще вполне возможен, особенно в тех случаях, когда множественное число имеет смысловой (не грамматический!) оттенок собирательности: *"Ты хочешь помидоры?"* и *"Ты хочешь помидоров?"* равноправны. А смысловое различие идет уже не по линии "конкретное"-"абстрактное", а по разделу "общее-частное".

Перейдем к грибам. Тоже издали.

*"Ты хочешь (жареные) подосиновики, подберезовики, шампиньоны, маслята?"* - никаких проблем. Как блюдо, кушанье... Шампиньоны, вроде, не жарят, но с грамматикой все в порядке.
*"Ты хочешь (жареных) подосиновиков, шампиньонов, подберезовиков, маслят?"* - тем более все ОК. Особенно, если речь идет о небольшой порции.

С "лисичками" хуже. Лисичка - слово грамматически одушевленное. Поэтому форма "лисичек" преобладает, хотя и *"хочешь лисички?"* вполне возможна.

Что ж такого происходит с опятами-опенками, что заставляет большинство носителей языка говорить именно *"Хочешь опят?"* вопреки всем вышевысказанным грамматическим соображениям?

Попробуем разобраться. Как было показано, сами по себе соображения о падеже и/или одушевленности ничего не определяют. Но, как совершенно верно заметила Екатерина, "опята" - это форма особая. Исторически "опята" было неправильным, слово "опенок" не имеет суффикса "-енок-": "-ен-" - от "пня", корень - "пен". Это абсолютно препятствовало образованию формы "опята", нормативным считалось "опенки" - и этим они отличались от "маслят". Поэтому *"хочешь опенки?"* (В.п) вполне успешно конкурировало с *"хочешь опенков"* (Р.п.)- и, видимо, даже преобладало.

Но дальше под влиянием *"масленок"-"маслята"* и т.п. де-факто произошло переразложение слова *"опенок"*, *"-енок-"* стало восприниматься как суффикс, порождающий во множественном числе новую форму "опята". И вот для этой-то новой формы, для которой соверешенно отсутствовала грамматическая традиция разделения родительного и винительного падежей, равно как само ощущение её неодушевленности, появилось закрепленное простой использования *"хочешь опят"* - как субъективно единственная возможная форма в обоих падежах и всех значениях. Но грамматически более правильную *"Хочешь опята?"* для винительного падежа (равно как и саму возможность использования винительного падежа для неодушевленных существительных) никто не отменял. Поэтому *"Ты хочешь опята?"* никак нельзя лишать прав на нормативность.

И в заключение. Разговоры про форму винительного падежа для всякой снеди редко проходят мимо ставшей знаменитой у филологов фразы "А я так люблю крабы" из "Иронии судьбы". 
Так вот, будьте уверены, герой Мягкова сказал все правильно. Во всяком случае - с точки зрения грамматики. 
Я здесь этим заявлением и ограничусь.

Comment: Непонятно, почему все зациклились на одушевленности или неодушевленности опят/козлят. Р.и В. падежи различаются значением (полный или частичный охват действием), а глагол хотеть (согласно Грамматике-80) имеет колеблющуюся переходность: хочу мороженое, торт - хочу конфет, печенья.

Comment: >колеблющуюся переходность  
  
Я не знаю этого термина.

на одушевленности никто не зацикливается. Наоборот, стараются её максимально ограничить. Но совсем без её привлечения всю проблему до конца не раскрыть. Проблема выбора падежа актуальна только для одушевленных существительных мужского рода I-го (академического) склонения... Я же пол ответа о том писал.

Comment: Термин взят из Грамматики-80, там говорится о том, что глаголы хотеть, желать, ждать, достигать, требовать, просить и некоторые другие имеют эту самую "колеблющуюся переходность". Это означает, что они могут управлять Р.п. или В.п., но с одушевленностью это не связано.

Answer (score 1):

Не все так просто.
"*Ты же сама приготовила из крабов, а я так люблю **крабы**!*" – цитата из всем известного фильма.
Чем крабы хуже опят? Люблю крабы, хочу опята...

Думаю, что оба варианта верны. Что с крабами, что с опятами.

Comment: Не знаю, как в словарях, но "люблю крабы" режет слух. Просится родительный/винительный "крабов". А это "люблю крабы" как-то на манер "я люблю родители" звучит.

Comment: Никак нет. Звучит наподобие "люблю грибы". "Крабы" здесь неодушевленное, и неспроста - они же в банках. )))

Answer (score 1):

Правильно: ты хочешь/хотел опят (Р.п.).   Неправильно: ты хочешь/хотел опята (В.п.)

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ

Ряд глаголов: хотеть, ждать, требовать, желать, просить - имеют колеблющуюся переходность. Это означает, что объект, которым управляет глагол, может употребляться в В.п.(переходный глагол)  и  в Р.п. (непереходный глагол).

Винительный падеж обозначает полный охват предмета действием, а родительный падеж обозначает действие, касающееся границ предмета (отложительно-достигательное значение Р.падежа).

Сравним: я хочу конфету (В.п., эту конкретную конфету) - я хочу конфет (Р.п., не все конфеты, которые существуют, а вообще конфет).

Comment: А почему в примере вы сравниваете множ. и ед. число? По аналогии с вопросом, ваш пример должен звучать как: "хочу конфету"(виню конфету, вн.пдж.) и "хочу конфеты"(нет конфеты,рд.пдж).

Comment: Винительный падеж направлен на объект и полностью охватывает его действием: хочу эту конфету (ед.ч. В.п.), но не этой конфеты (ед.ч.Р.п.). А вот хотеть эти конфеты (В.п. мн.ч.) - так не говорят, сложно хотеть все конфеты сразу. Поэтому мы говорим: хочу конфет.

Answer (score 0):

..Падежи..
В данном случае - винительный.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ